# jquery tabs with design in css

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

Here is what I am trying to get to:

[image]
My deisgner has given me the upper line shadow, the lowe line shadow and the "curve".
I cannot figure out how to implement them to get the desired result.

Thanks

EDIT:
Since I can not add an image to a reply, I am editing my question.
I don't think border-radius and shadow can get me there.
I have gotten this far...
[image]

Any more thoughts?

EDIT:
Here is the CSS:

```
height: 57px;
border: medium none;
top: 14px;
margin: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 2px;
```

Notice, how I don't get the full "slide" between the 2 tabs.

Comment: can you post the code you have used?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to achieve Curve and Shadow.

**For curve**

```
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 12px;
```

**For shadow**

```
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
   box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

**The parameters respectively means :**

The horizontal offset of the shadow, positive means the shadow will be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on the left of the box.

The vertical offset of the shadow, a negative one means the box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow will be below the box.

The blur radius (optional), if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp, the higher the number, the more blurred it will be.

The spread radius (optional), positive values increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur).

Color